# Crystal Reports same data displayed three times using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am creating a simple inventory system in C#. When I am printing a receipt, I have to join `sales` and `sales product` tables. In Crystal Report, I had a problem on `sales_product` table - data is displayed three times - see the attached screen shot:

[image]

Crystal Report design

[image]

I have joined `sales` and `sales product` table to get the result.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT sales.id, sales.subtotal, sales.pay,sales.bal,sales_product.sales_id,sales_product.prodname,sales_product.price,sales_product.qty,sales_product.total FROM sales INNER JOIN sales_product ON sales.id=sales_product.sales_id where sales_product.sales_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "sales");
da.Fill(ds, "sales_product");

cryRpt.Load("c:/users/kobinath/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication48/WindowsFormsApplication48/CrystalReport1.rpt");
 cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: i check out i don't know how to solve the problem any problem with dataset

Comment: Try following : DataSet ds = new DataSet(); DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt1, "sales"); ds.Tables.Add(dt1);DataTable  dt2 = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt2, "sales_product"); ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

Comment: da.Fill(dt1, "sales"); this line getting error sir

Comment: I think jdweng means you should break your query into two queries. So, create two SqlDataAdapter instances (remove the join). Make it work. The problem will probably still exist, but it is an important step. Then we talk how to solve it. Show your data.